# Mutiple cursors and other errors in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

My jupyter notebook has been behaving differently from today morning. Following are the errors

1. Whenever I run a cell its cursors remain there [Check this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBaLk.png)
2. When I press "tab" for autocomplete. It just moves the line by tab instead of autocomplete or suggestion.

I tried uninstalling and installing anaconda (for LINUX). Can I anyone tell me why it is happening and how to fix it?